# Image data from database not showing in stimulsoft report

Tags: c#, reporting, stimulsoft

I stored collection images in database (create field img as byte[]) and when passed into stimulsoft report is not showing.!
I try to create field img in stimulsoft designer as byte[] or image... but is not working.!
How to display it ?

```
var imgConverter = new ImageConvert();
var report = new StiReport();
var t = new DataTable();

t.Columns.Add("Img");

foreach (DataGridViewRow dgv in dataGridViewX3.Rows)
{
    t.Rows.Add(
       imgConverter.ByteArrayToImage((byte[])dgv.Cells["BarcodeImg"].Value)
    );
}
report.Load("BarcodeReport.mrt");
report.RegData("DSBarcode", t);
report.Compile();
report.Show();
```

Comment: Please share some code to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array of bytes (byte[]) to send image:

```
dtModel.Columns.Add("Pic", typeof(byte[]))
```

and try to send the array. then you should assign the parameter to the image in Stimulsoft(by using DataColumn property).